# Python: LPTHW Ex. 39, get function, default variable. ELI5

Tags: python, default-value

My first question here, so be gentle, please.

As stated in question, I'm in LPTHW Ex. 39. I need help understanding the default variable in the `get` function. I guess I don't quite understand why it's defined with `default=None` as an argument (or why the `get_slot` function did the same) and uses the argument `default=default` when it strips the `v` off to return for later use in `ex39_test.py`

I have had no trouble finding answers to anything else. This seems simple, but no other source has been clear on this subject.

For reference:
[The LPTHW Ex. 39 can be read here.](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html)

The section I'm confused on deals with this section of code from `hashmap.py`:

```
def get(aMap, key, default=None):
    """Gets the value in a bucket for the given key, or the default."""
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key, default=default)
    return v
```

I understand what the function does, and I understand most of the how. That default is throwing me though. I'd also like to know as much why as reasonably possible so that the concept is useful in the future.

ELI5, please.

Note: I'm assuming that `'Does Not Exist'` in the last section of `ex39_test.py` (the only portion to call this function) is (re?)setting(?) the default, but I don't feel confident that this is correct or complete.

Again for reference:

```
city = hashmap.get(cities, 'TX', 'Does Not Exist')
print "The city for the state 'TX' is: %s" % city
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you dont understend exactly? what get does or what the purpose for the default?

Comment: What's the purpose of assigning the default to default=None and default=default?

What do they do that is different from the built-in default values? (Isn't that None already?)

I understand that get returns the third argument that it is given. That's clear. I need help with understanding the default value's role in all of this.

Sorry I wasn't clear before.

Comment: In `get_slot(aMap, key, default=default)` first default is the name of the keyword argument. The second default is the value you assign to this argument.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `get_slot` with the default value the caller has passed to your `get` function, which is `default`. If the caller doesn't pass in anything, `default` is `None`, but if they did pass in anything, you want to pass along whatever that is, instead of always passing `None`.